# Querying post from a multisite network

Tags: posts, wp-query, multisite, recent-posts

I am working on a multisite blog network where I have to display recent post on my home page, 10 post per page navigation.

I did implement it using wpdb object with one complex sql statement.

- I got blog ids us `get_blog_list` function
- looped through each blog id list and generated a one single sql query to get post from all sites
- Used `wpdb->get_result` to get list of posts from all subsites

I have recently started working on PHP and WordPress and am still learning it.

Is use of `wpdb` object is the right way in this situation? I have read in many articles which uses `WP_Query` object. I don't know how to use `WP_Query` object in this situation?

Help me implement this in right/better way.

Comment: Please post you code. What is the significance of the 'multisite' part of the title? Are you pulling posts from one site into another? Or pulling posts from the same site?

Answer (score 6):

You could use your list of blog ids in this way ...

```
$posts = array();
foreach ( $your_list_of_blog_ids as $blog_id ) {
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    $query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'any',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
        )
    );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->next_post();
        $posts[] = $query->post;
    }
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Important are [switch_to_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog) and [restore_current_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/restore_current_blog). The rest of the code is just there to illustrate the idea.